# django if condition not working when using variable, but when using number it's working

Tags: python, django

why this code not working, i get variable "data" from views.py

when i change data.numrooms with number like '1', it's working well, but is use data.numrooms that's not working

```
<select class="form-control" name="numadults">
      <option value=''>No. of Adult</option>
          {% for i in range %}
             {% if data.numadults == i %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
             {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
             {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Where do You use `data.numrooms`? I see only `data.numadults`.

Comment: what is `range`? and show us `data`

Answer (score 1):

Why not put that logic in the view and pass it to template like this:

```
# view

adult_range = list(map(lambda x: (x, True) if x == data.numadults else (x, False), range(1,10))

# Template
  <option value=''>No. of Adult</option>
      {% for i, selected in adult_range %}
         {% if selected %}
            <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
         {% else %}
            <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to ruddra's solution, the easiest way to achieve this is probably to do the bulk of the logic in the view:

```
adults = [(element, element.number == data.numadults) for element in adult_list]
```

This will give you a list of two-tuples of `(<adult object>, <boolean>)` where the boolean represents the conditional you're trying to use in the template to decide whether to use `selected` attribute.

In the template, you can then base your conditional solely on that boolean:

```
<option value=''>No. of Adult</option>
{% for i, selected in adult_range %}
    {% if selected %}
        <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note though that you can also evaluate the condition inline, in the html tag, like so:

```
<option value="{{ i }}" {% if selected %} selected {% endif %}>
```

This might make for more readable code.